# SSIS: How to replace asterisk, data type DT_R8, excel source

Tags: excel, ssis

In Data Flow task I am trying to replace * with Data Flow component "Derived Column" using the following expression:
`REPLACE(Code, "*", " ")` - but this simple replace statement will not work, I have also tried to cast "Code" as DT_WSTR, but no help so far. Hopefully someone know how to do it. "Code" value is coming from excel source and data type for it is DT_R8

> Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column 1 [57]]: The function
>   "REPLACE" does not support the data type "DT_R8" for parameter number
>   1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this operation, the
>   operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Comment: What exactly are you using Excel VBA macro or Excel function?. Please post a sample with input and desired output.

Comment: I have added some additional info into orig. post.

Comment: DT_R8 is a number and replace only works on strings. A number should not have a "*" in it

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it, in excel there can be such value 234432* - but data type is set based on first row in excel, if I am correct when selecting data from excel source with SSIS. I tried to cast value as string, but it did not help. My goal is to get rid of this asterisk somehow.